# Android - Unit test on the class that calls JNI functions?

Tags: android, unit-testing, java-native-interface

I am working on an 2.2 android platform, and
I have a java class that gathers a list of JNI functions.

Now I am going to do the unit test on this class, but my IDE wont let me with this error msg:
"java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no nativeInterface in java.library.path"

Is there any setting or things that I should do before I do the unit test on this kind of class?

Thanks in advance.

--Terry

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't have the JNI folder and all the native files (`.c`, `.h`) in your project.

Comment: Well, I do have .c .h files, and an android.mk file. Everything is fine when the application is running without any unit-tests.

Comment: then u can give native support to ur esclipse  Sequoyah Metadata Repository
http://download.eclipse.org/sequoyah/updates/1.1/

Comment: I tried sequoyah before. But, our customer requires us to use IntelliJ instead of Eclipse. And our project cannot be compiled in eclipse. I guess sequayah wont work on IntelliJ. Is that correct? Thanks for your information.